# XCode error: cannot overwrite dSYM file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dsym

Again and again on every project running I'm getting the same error. Sometimes deleting derived data helps, sometimes it doesn't.

This started after my team leader had accepted new license agreement for the iOS Team Development Program, I suppose, but I'm not sure.

What can be the cause of the problem? 
How can I fix it?

```
  (null): error: No such file or directory - old dSYM file cannot be overwritten:       old: '/Users/.../Xcode/DerivedData/Project-gzbujuaqsogtbwbatsbvviqtmsqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Project'
```

update:

Also, I've noticed that some duplicated schemes appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this problem because I had the same target (the tests corresponding to a framework) repeated twice. I delete one of them and the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean your project?

Build -> Clean

Or

Cmd (+Shift?) + K

Comment: Yes, I have to do this every time I'm trying to build the project. Also I delete derived data. But sometimes it works, sometime not.